# How to create database apps?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

How to create database apps?
I have a textbox, button and label. The user enters a value = Luke and the program does the Select Address From Customers where Name='Luke'. It displays Address in the label.

I know this is a pretty stupid question, but I've looked everywhere, and all I can find is how to display all columns instead of just one thing.

Anymore advice on databases with c# would be very help as well. I am using Sql server Express 2012 and Visual Studio

The Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SelectData(textBox1.Text);
        }
        private void SelectData(string selectConnection)
        {
            string connectionStr =
                @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"+
                @"AttachDbFilename=C:\SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases\NORTHWND.MDF;"+
                @"Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Address FROM Customers"+
                " WHERE CustomerName = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor: don't mix UI and database like this.  Separate them out so you can test them independently.  Don't you just need to refine your query?

Comment: I think you should google `C# getting started with sql tutorial` before asking for help... I know getting started isn't easy but you won't get better if you ask before searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An advice for C# and Databases would be, to not put a string command together in the application. 
There are many roads to success but some may lead to an unsecure Database query.

Personally I don't use, for example, the Entity Framework(Microsoft recommendation) etc. but I guess they might be helpfull for what you do so you should take a look at this.

Try to seperate the SQL Logic from the C# part so that **IF** your application grows and you can effort a Database administrator he doesn't have to know c# ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the perfect track, now continuation to your code to display the address you can write like this:

```
label_address.text=command.executescalar();//if you have one row of address
```

else you can write

```
datareader dr =cmd.executereader()
while(dr.read())
{
label_address+=dr(0).tostring();+","//addressline1
label_address+=dr(1).tostring();//addressline2
}
```

hope its helpful